# Gracenote Entourage Initialization Error

Tags: iphone, gracenote

I received my Entourage License Info and attempting to test the GN_Entourage_Demo.

However, when inputting the Client ID, Tag and License String in the appropriate #define lines in GNViewController.m, I receive the following errors:

**2014-03-10 19:05:20.506 GN_Entourage_Demo[24927:70b] getUserACR: ERROR: Manager not initialized
2014-03-10 19:05:20.509 GN_Entourage_Demo[24927:70b] Error: Invalid User
(lldb)**

I have tried various permutations and even used second Entourage License but I get the same error. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22874005/1588901

You probably need to replace newlines in the License String with '\n'