# Gracenote Error: Invalid User

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gracenote

Problem to implement Gracenote api in iOS provide invalid User & manager not initialised .

GN_Entourage_Demo[24927:70b] getUserACR: ERROR: Manager not initialized 2014-03-10 19:05:20.509 GN_Entourage_Demo[24927:70b] Error: Invalid User (lldb)
 following problem when i am implement

// Initialize the Entourage SDK
    self.sdkManager = [[GnSdkManager alloc] initWithLicense:LICENSE_INFO error:nil];

```
self.acrUser = [self getUserACR];
if (!self.acrUser) {
    NSLog(@"Error: Invalid User");
}

// Create a GnAcr object for this user
self.acr = [[GnACR alloc] initWithUser:self.acrUser error:nil];

// Set up an audio configuration
GnAcrAudioConfig *config =
[[[GnAcrAudioConfig alloc] initWithAudioSourceType:GnAcrAudioSourceMic
                                        sampleRate:GnAcrAudioSampleRate44100
                                            format:GnAcrAudioSampleFormatPCM16
                                       numChannels:1] autorelease];

// Initialize the GnAcr's audio configuration
[self.acr audioInitWithAudioConfig:config];

// Initialize the audio source (i.e. device microphone)
self.audioSource = [[GnAudioSourceiOSMic alloc] initWithAudioConfig:config];

// Assign the delegates
self.audioSource.audioDelegate = self;
self.acr.resultDelegate = self;
self.acr.statusDelegate = self;

self.isListening = NO;
```

}

Comment: That's not enough information to answer the question.  Please show the code that calls the Gracenote API.

Comment: What happen if you use the parameter `error` in your methods and see their values instead of putting `nil`?

Comment: i am actually used demo tutorial download from gracenote api sit so i am face this problem when used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS code has a problem with whitespace/newlines in the LICENSE_INFO literal. What you need to do is replace newlines in your License String with '\n' (without the quotes), so that LICENSE_INFO is just one long line. The error should go away.

We've updated the docs with this note https://developer.gracenote.com/how-build-simple-entourage-application-ios

Thanks, and sorry for the inconvenience!